# Issues with colon (:) in when next to variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the following to work so I can automate some SCP uploads I need to do. I believe the problem is how `${user}@${device}` is being interpreted.

```bsh
$user = "user1"
$device = "server1"
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' `
-ArgumentList ("c:\temp\myfile.txt ${user}@${device}:/shared/tmp/") -NoNewWindow
```

I've tried `$user@$device` (powershell barks about syntax), `$user@${device}`and `${user}@${device}` (these tell me you can't copy from local to local which indicates in is not parsing the `:/shared/tmp/` correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, unless you have a specific reason for using `Start-Process`: don't bother. Use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) (`&`) instead.

This worked perfectly fine when I just tested it:

```
$user   = 'user1'
$device = 'server1'
$params = 'c:\temp\myfile.txt', "${user}@${device}:/shared/tmp/"

& 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' @params
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also escape the `:` with `` ` ``:

```
"c:\temp\myfile.txt ${user}@${device}`:/shared/tmp/"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user = "user1"
$device = "server1"
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe' `
-ArgumentList ("c:\temp\myfile.txt {$($user)}@{$($device)}:/shared/tmp/") -NoNewWindow
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$user = "user1"
$device = "server1"
$Program='C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe'
$Arguments="c:\temp\myfile.txt {0}@{1}:/shared/tmp/ -NoNewWindow" -f $user, $device
Start-Process $Program  $Arguments
```